# React-Native ListView onPress - undefined is not an object

Tags: react-native

I seem to be stuck with calling functions on button press. No matter what method i try i get different undefined errors.

i'm running react native 0.24 and currently coding for Android device only.

please see the code below:

```
class ListPage extends Component {

   constructor(props){
   super(props);
       this.nav = props.nav;
       this.route = props.route;
       this.ds = new ListView.DataSource({
          rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
       });
       this.state = ({
           visible: false,
           dataSource: this.ds.cloneWithRows(props.fullList),
       });
  }

  goToPage(name){
      this.nav.push({ name: name });
  }

  loadModal() {
      this.setState({ visible: true });
  }

    list(row){
        return (
             <View style={styles.box}>
                  <TouchableNativeFeedback underlayColor="#FFF" 
                    onPress={this.goToPage.bind(this,'ShowRow')}>
                      <View>
                          ...ShowRow Button
                      </View>
                   </TouchableNativeFeedback>
                   <TouchableNativeFeedback
                      onPress={this.loadModal.bind(this)} >
                        <View style={styles.button}>
                            ...Modal Button
                        </View>
                   </TouchableNativeFeedback>
              </View>
          );
    }

    render(){
        return (
             <View style={styles.container}>
                <Modal visible={this.state.visible}
                  onRequestClose={() => {this.setState({visible: false}) }} >
                    <View>
                        <Text>I am a Modal!</Text>
                    </View>
                </Modal>
                <ListView
                  dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                  renderRow={this.list} />
             </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Whenever i press either button i get undefined is not an object error for both this.goToPage.bind and this.loadModal.bind .

if i try this:

```
render() { //or inside list(row) function
    goToPage = function(name){
       this.nav.push etc etc
    }
    loadModal = function() { setState etc... }
    return (
        ...render stuff
    )
}
```

it now says undefined is not an object for both this.nav and this.setState

but if i do this:

```
 constructor() {
    ...
    goToPage = function(name){
        props.nav.push(...);
    }
 }
```

it works.....but i know this is not the right approach and also i can't setState for the modal. Why isn't it working with the first method? Many thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Okay, found the solution. in renderRow, i needed to bind the function like so:

```
<ListView dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
renderRow={this.list.bind(this)} />
```

Now i can call the functions with the first method.